# ViewPager - RecyclerView - AppBar Scrolling Issue

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, fragment

I am developing in `Xamarin` one application, but I am having an issue with `ViewPager` swiping between tabs. `ViewPager` contains some `Fragments`, while fragments contains only `RecyclerCiew` inside.

The issue is that when I have reached really top or bottom of `RecyclerView`, then if I try to **swipe left or right between pages** instead of `ViewPager` to take action, the `RecyclerView` is swiping up or down instead.

Only if there is a little gap of space then I can swipe between tabs, but not when I am at really top or bottom.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayoutMain"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
      <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
          android:id="@+id/toolbar1Main"
          app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp" 
          app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
          app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
      <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
          android:id="@+id/tabLayout1Main"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
          app:tabMode="scrollable" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager1Main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
     </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```